I have a question about formulas in SharePoint fields
I have a SharePoint list that contains several questions (much like a survey). Each question has a choice field with selections for 'Yes', 'No', and 'N/A'. A value must be assigned based upon the answer: 'Yes'= 1, 'No'=0, and 'N/A' = BLANK.
My task is to sum and count all the 'Yes', 'No', 'N/A' answers separately and divide them by the total (by count and sum). I have built a calc of sorts using the questions to refer to the fields. My issue is that some of these questions are VERY long. By default, SharePoint did this. So once I start entering my references between the operands, the formula becomes very long and challenging to read.
Is there a way to shorten this by using aliases? Instead of "Q1. Was the patient observed at any time by the Q-coordinator modeling the correct behavior, blah, blah... + Q2... +" to "a. + b. + c..." I know use of the alias is possible in MS Access and I think SQL. Any thoughts about this?
I appreciate any feedback you may have.
Regards,
Ben

Per my knowledge, there is no way to alias a SharePoint column, we need to get the value of the specified column and participate in the calculation via [full name of the column].
If you really need to streamline your formulas, you can create corresponding auxiliary columns for your long-named columns, keep their values consistent, and then use the auxiliary columns to participate in the calculations in your formula. Don't forget to modify the view to not show these auxiliary columns.
